# Why there is a different redux-multi package installed with yarn?

Tags: javascript, npm, redux, yarnpkg

I've switched to `yarn` package manager due to some performance issues had with `npm`.
Everything went fine but having an issue with [redux-multi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-multi) not being the same as it was with `npm`.
Has anyone experienced this before? What should be the best solution for this? I don't really want to update my application's code.

Yarn:

```
function multi(_ref) {
  var dispatch = _ref.dispatch;

  return function (next) {
    return function (action) {
      return Array.isArray(action) ? Promise.all(action.filter(Boolean).map(function (p) {
        return dispatch(p);
      })) : next(action);
    };
  };
}
```

Npm:

```
function multi(_ref) {
  var dispatch = _ref.dispatch;

  return function (next) {
    return function (action) {
      return Array.isArray(action) ? action.filter(Boolean).map(dispatch) : next(action);
    };
  };
}
```

Notice the difference: the yarn version uses `Promise`.

Comment: How have you defined the dependency in `package.json`?

Comment: `"redux-multi": "^0.1.12",` - I've checked both version and they are the same.

Comment: How, exactly, did you check the version? Also, what version is shown in your `yarn.lock` file?

Comment: Ok, you're right! For some reason I made a mistake when checking the versions. Yarn lock: 0.1.91 - Can you answer this question so that I can accept it. :)

Comment: It only needs to be locked to 0.1.12 ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention that your `package.json` file uses `^0.1.12` which means "any version compatible with `0.1.12`.

`yarn` adds another level of reliability on top of `npm` which is meant to protect other developers from installing different compatible versions across environments.

I would check your `yarn.lock` file and ensure that it also has the version that you're expecting to be installed (vs. `npm`).

Personally, I always pin my requirements in situations like this (just using a specific version rather than one of the modifiers).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the solution! What I found weird is that I could only see the `0.1.12` version on the npm site. Where should I be looking for the `yarn` versions? I've tried to find the package from the `yarnpkg.com` but it eventually redirects to npm site.

Comment: @haxpanel - `yarn` doesn't have its own versions. It just downloads from `npm`.

Comment: Then shouldn't be `0.1.91` displayed on the npm site?

Comment: @haxpanel - Definitely. Not sure what's going on. I don't see any tags or versions on the GitHub page for the project either.

Comment: Anyways, thank you again - now I know where to confirm versions .. :)